# Soft binning with numpy histogramdd

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I am trying to soft bin my data using np.histogramdd, but I could not find a solution anywhere.

Here is what I mean. Say I have my data:

```
data = np.array([[1.8, 3.1]])
```

If I compute the histogram as follows

```
h, _ = np.histogramdd(data, bins=(5,5), range=[(0,5), (0,5)])
```

the output is

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Since NumPy uses hard binning, a bin gets either a 1 or a 0 (in this case) depending on if a data point lands in that bucket. Take, for instance, the row with a `1` since the first data point `[1.8, 3.1]` falls within `bin=(1, 3)` it gets a `1` in the first-row third col (index starts at 0).

However, I would like to use soft binning. That is, I want the output to be

```
array([[0., 0., 0.,   0.,   0.],
       [0., 0., 0.28, 0.42, 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.12, 0.18, 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.,   0.,   0.],
       [0., 0., 0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

That is since `1.8` is closer to row-1 bin center than to row-2 bin center, (`1.8 - 1.5 = .3` < `2.5 - 1.8 = .7`) row-1 gets `.7` while row-2 gets `.3`. Now we have to compute the cols. Since `3.1` is closer to `3.5` than to `2.5` (row-1,col-3) gets `.6*.7=.42` (row-1,col-2) gets `.4*.7=.28`. We can compute the same proprtion for row-2 to get my desiered results.

How do I accomplish this? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more information about how the weighting is done? Your example seems to be specific for the situation where the bin (center) distance is `1` and thus happens to coincide with the total bin increment (`1` as well). What if ranges were `[(0, 10), (0, 10)]`?

Comment: to compute the weight you simply take `1-distance` For example if the distance is .3 the weight will be `1-.3 = .7`

Comment: What if distance is greater than 1? I suppose you'd like to just normalize to 1 in that case, i.e. `left_contribution = left_distance / (left_distance + right_distance)` and `right_contribution = right_distance / (left_distance + right_distance)`; is that correct?

Comment: yes that's right